# createWriteStream success upload image but not generate access token

Tags: node.js, google-cloud-storage, sharp

I've a image stream that result from sharp, after resizing the image I wanna upload it to google storage.
Here is my code:

```
const remoteWriteStream = storage
    .bucket(storageBucket)
    .file('products/'+mediumName)
    .createWriteStream({
        metadata: {
            contentType: 'image/jpeg'
        }
    });

sharp(result)
    .resize({width: 1440})
    .pipe(remoteWriteStream)
    .on('finish', () => {
        resolve(mediumCloud);
        console.log("IMAGE PATH: ", url)
    });
```

it successfully create file in cloud storage, with datatype 'image/jpeg'. But it can't view, when I tried to open the file, the preview on right side only show loading. I thought it was caused the access token is not defined. Howw do I can set the access token for each upload?

Comment: *"I see the last word in the url is like 'undefined'"* - that sounds like `mediumName` is undefined.  You probably have some debugging to do.

Comment: but a new imagee has inserted in bucket named exactly like `mediumName`.

Comment: Where exactly you are trying to view it? in GCP console -> Storage -> Browser-> Bucket-> file?